# Copying Google Gloud Datastore entities from one namespace to an other

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm copying Google Cloud Datastore entities from one namespace to an other with java like this:

```
Key newKey = Key.newBuilder(oldEntity.getKey()).setNamespace(NEW_NAMESPACE).build();
datastore.put(Entity.newBuilder(oldEntity).setKey(newKey).build());
```

Since the entities have numerid id's generated by Datastore and the id's of the copied entities need to remain the same I need to also let Datastore know to allocate these id's, for that I'm using `DatastoreService.allocateIdRange`

But this is giving me an error:

> Exceeded maximum allocated IDs

Does this mean that there is no way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve?

EDIT 1

The code that allocates the ids:

```
@POST
public void post(
        @QueryParam("namespace") String namespace,
        @QueryParam("kind") String kind,
        @QueryParam("id") long id,
        @QueryParam("parentKind") String parentKind,
        @QueryParam("parentName") String parentName,
        @QueryParam("parentId") Long parentId
) {
    NamespaceManager.set(namespace);
    DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Key parent = null;
    if (parentKind != null) {
        if (parentName != null)
            parent = KeyFactory.createKey(parentKind, parentName);
        else
            parent = KeyFactory.createKey(parentKind, parentId);
    }
    ds.allocateIdRange(new KeyRange(parent, kind, id, id));
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you exceeded the [limit](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits) of 500 allocated IDs per operation?

Comment: No, I had to do it one by one.

Comment: @Heigo Can we see the code where you call `allocateIdRange`? If you're calling it in a loop or something you could actually have allocated all of the IDs.

Comment: I know the same key IDs can be used with a different key ancestry (i.e. different entity groups), but docs don't appear to mention if the same is true for just a different namespace. If it's not true that most likely explains the error.

Comment: @Venantius I'm doing this in a separate request, since I have to be able to access it from outside of AppEngine. So this can not be the issue.

Comment: @DanCornilescu To my knowledge entities nor entities in two different namespaces do not affect each other. Also there was no problem creating the entities in the new namespace, the problem was with allocating the id's

Comment: @Heigo: exactly what I'm talking about: check if you have the same key ID in different namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can skip the key creation. This is my code for updating namespaces:

```
GoogleCloudDatastore gds = new GoogleCloudDatastore();
Datastore ds = gds.getCredentials();

final KeyFactory keyFactory = ds.newKeyFactory().setKind(entityKind).setNamespace(NAME_SPACE);
Key newKey = ds.allocateId(oldEntity.getKey);
Entity newEntity= Entity.newBuilder(newKey).set("someParameterName", someParameterValue).build();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [answer](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77988981) provided on Google's Issue Tracker:

> allocateIdRange only works with Sequential contiguous IDs and not Scattered IDs which are above the Sequential ID range.
>
> As explained in the ['Best Practices'](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#keys) documentation, if need be it is recommended to send an 'allocateIds' request to Datastore to find and allocate a contiguous [range of unique IDs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService.html#allocateIds-java.lang.String-long-) and use those to save entities to, instead of saving entities to the Datastore first which are auto-assigned [Scattered IDs](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2013/05/update-on-datastore-auto-ids.html) and cannot be allocated with allocateIdRange.